# javascript : calculating and returning values after Image loaded

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous, return, onload

I already checked multiple responses to asynchronous javascript behaviours and experimented with callbacks, experimenting with promises next, but parallell I want to send SoS request here :/

Because often first answers are  ("What do you want to do?")

I have to find out all the non-empty or transparent pixels in an Image.(kinda like a mask) and give them back an array of binary arithmetical numbers.

What my program does in short:

- it gets Image URL and creates `new Image()` from it.
- it creates a Canvas and adds it to DOM
- in `image.onLoad()` it draws the image on the canvas
- after the Image is on canvas, it scans every pixel for its color and gives back a data array.

My problem is to force the calculation to WAIT until the image is loaded. I tried to do with something like this:

```
return getDataArray(image.onLoad()= function(){
    // ...init things...
}));
```

Still, it goes into the `getDataArray` function, before the `image.onLoad` happens.

I'm gonna take a break and walk outside because I'm out of productive ideas.

Here is the original function:

```
getImageScan: function() {
    this.myImage.src = imageScanner.imgUrl;
    var is = this;
    return  is.getArrayFromCanvas(this.myImage.onload = function () {
        is.imageHeight = is.myImage.height;
        is.imageWidth = is.myImage.width;
        is.appendCanvasToBody();
        is.initGraphicalContent();
        is.drawImageOnCanvas();
        console.log("image is loaded");
    })
},

getArrayFromCanvas: function () {
    console.log("request for calculations");
    var booleanJson = this.getJsonFromCanvas()
    return this.getBinaryArithmeticFromBooleans(booleanJson);
}
```

and this is the result

request for calculations

```
[]
```

the image is loaded

here is the entire *.js if you want more information (it's my private project in slacktime, so no copyright issues):

https://github.com/Vilkaz/gridToImage/blob/master/web/resources/js/imageScanner.js

Answer (score 1):

You try to pass something to `getArrayFromCanvas` although it has no parameters. I don't understand why you do this, but I guess you want something like this:

```
getImageScan: function(callback) {
  this.myImage.src = imageScanner.imgUrl;
  var is = this;
  this.myImage.onload = function () {
    is.imageHeight = is.myImage.height;
    is.imageWidth = is.myImage.width;
    is.appendCanvasToBody();
    is.initGraphicalContent();
    is.drawImageOnCanvas();
    console.log("image is loaded");
    callback(is.getArrayFromCanvas());
  }
}
```

One difference between the asynchronous behavior above and your original code is that `getImageScan` returns immediately and that a callback is called later to "return" the result.